# infowindow.setContent shows only one record

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am working on a project in Laravel.

This is my script that I have done to display a map with multiple markers with Google Maps. I have 2 json objects that I am retrieving one with the locations and one with autos. A location can have many autos, so it is a one to many relationship.

What i am trying to do is that in the `infowindow.setContent` to display a description of the location and the autos that belong to the location.
The map, the markers with the proper locations are displayed correctly. But in the `infowindow.setContent` are displayed the description and the title of the location and the last record of the autos that belong to that location.

When the script is run the `console.log` displays the information as it has to be. that means that my loop for autos is working fine but when i pass the result to the `infowindow.setContent` it reads only the last record.

This is my first time asking for help here, so excuse me if I'm not clear enough. I would be very grateful to anyone that responds to me.

My Script:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">  

    var locations = @json($locations);
    var autos = @json($autos);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


    var mymap = new GMaps({
        el: '#mymap',
        center: {lat: 41.323029, lng: 19.817856},
        zoom:6
    });



    $.each( locations, function( index, value ){

        mymap.addMarker({
            lat: value.lat,
            lng: value.long,
            title: value.title,
            click: function(e) {

                for (var auto in autos)
                {
                    if(autos[auto].location_id == value.id)
                    {

                        var autoBrands =autos[auto].brand;
                        console.log(autoBrands);

                    }
                }


                infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + autoBrands + '</strong><br></div>'+  '<div><strong>' + value.title + '</strong><br></div>' + '<div><strong>' + value.description + '</strong><br></div>');

                infowindow.open(mymap, this);

            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just reassigning value of `autoBrands` inside your loop. Why don't you create it as an array object? Something like

```
<script  type="text/javascript">  

  var locations = @json($locations);
  var autos = @json($autos);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


  var mymap = new GMaps({
      el: '#mymap',
      center: {lat: 41.323029, lng: 19.817856},
      zoom:6
  });



  $.each( locations, function( index, value ){

      mymap.addMarker({
          lat: value.lat,
          lng: value.long,
          title: value.title,
          click: function(e) {

              var autoBrands = [];
              for (var auto in autos)
              {
                  if(autos[auto].location_id == value.id)
                  {

                      autoBrands.push(autos[auto].brand);
                      console.log(autoBrands);

                  }
              }


              infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + autoBrands.join(",") + '</strong><br></div>'+  '<div><strong>' + value.title + '</strong><br></div>' + '<div><strong>' + value.description + '</strong><br></div>');

              infowindow.open(mymap, this);

          }
      });

  });
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're looping over all your locations, adding a marker for each.  However you only have one `infowindow` variable. On each iteration of the loop, you're updating what the content of the same infowindow will be, so it ends up just getting the content from the very last iteration.

Have a separate function that opens the infowindow in response to the user's click, something like this:

```
$.each( locations, function( index, value ){
    mymap.addMarker({
        lat: value.lat,
        lng: value.long,
        title: value.title,
        click: function(e) {
            for (var auto in autos)
            {
                if(autos[auto].location_id == value.id)
                {
                    var autoBrands =autos[auto].brand;
                    console.log(autoBrands);
                }
            }

            openInfowindow(
                '<div><strong>' + autoBrands + '</strong><br></div>'+  '<div><strong>' + value.title + '</strong><br></div>' + '<div><strong>' + value.description + '</strong><br></div>',
                this
            );
        }
    });
});

function openInfowindow(content, marker)
{
    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.open(mymap, marker);
}
```